# How do I construct a Schauder basis of $l^2$ with the set $\{v_n\}

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

How do I construct a Schauder basis of $l^2$ with the set $\{v_n\} \subset l^2$, where $v_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(e_n-e_{n+1})$ if $n$ is odd and $v_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(e_n+e_{n-1})$ if $n$ even. Note that this set is orthonormal so it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n$ be even; write $n=2k$. Then $v_n = v_{2k} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (e_{2k} + e_{2k-1})$ and $v_{n-1} = v_{2k-1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (e_{2k-1} - e_{2k})$. Hence $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} (v_n + v_{n-1}) = e_{2k-1} = e_{n-1}$. So this allows you to represent any $e_n$ for odd $n$.

Use a similar construction to represent $e_n$ for even $n$. Since you can represent any $e_n$, the "Schauder span" of your set is all of $\ell^2$. Since your set is orthonormal it is also linearly independent. So it is a Schauder basis.

Comment: $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(v_n-v_{n+1})=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(e_{2k}+e_{2k-1})-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(e_{2k-1}+e_{2k})=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}e_{2k}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}e_{2k-1}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}e_{2k-1}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}e_{2k})=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}2e_{2k}=e_n$. How can we represent a vector in $l^2$ in terms of this basis?

Comment: If you have $x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n e_n$. Now plug in your expression for $e_n$ in each term, obtaining $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_n v_{2k} + \sum_{k=1}^\infty b_n v_{2k-1}$ for appropriate $a_n,b_n$.

Comment: I wrote it differently but your way is better